ObjectMapper in RestClient not picking up configuration properties
In my Spring Boot service, I'm using RestClient to perform REST calls. I want to ignore null values in request bodies so I set up
spring:
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: "non_null"

in my application.yml. However, the config is not respected for some reason in the RestClient's ObjectMapper. On the other hand, when I inject the Spring auto-configured ObjectMapper into my test class (annotated with @SpringBootTest) I see the mapper configured as expected. What could be the reason for RestClient picking up a different ObjectMapper than the one configured by Spring Boot?
Couple of notes:

I'm not configuring ObjectMapper in any other way than via application.yml
I'm doing RestClient.create() to set up the RestClient
I don't use @EnableWebMvc (the usual suspect in similar SO questions)


You need to, at least, use RestClient.create(restTemplate). Your RestTemplate needs to be configured with the ObjectMapper you need.
When you use RestClient.create() it has no way of picking up spring-configured mapper, how could it? It's regular java object creation.
There are some other options, for example:
RestClient.builder()
  .messageConverters(in -> {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setPrettyPrint(false);
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    in.add(jacksonConverter);
  })
.build();


Of course. I started doubting myself right after I posted this. The RestClient is actually set up in some central company library and I for some reason believed that the authors knew what they were doing. They didn't :-)

The correct Spring Boot way to obtain a RestClient instance is probably to autowire RestClient.Builder.
